# OpenCV Stereo matching and disparity map

Tags: image, opencv

I am using the code sample for stereo matching that came with openCV source code, here:

```
/*
 *  stereo_match.cpp
 *  calibration
 *
 *  Created by Victor  Eruhimov on 1/18/10.
 *  Copyright 2010 Argus Corp. All rights reserved.
 *
 */

#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

static void print_help()
{
    printf("\nDemo stereo matching converting L and R images into disparity and point clouds\n");
    printf("\nUsage: stereo_match <left_image> <right_image> [--algorithm=bm|sgbm|hh|var] [--blocksize=<block_size>]\n"
           "[--max-disparity=<max_disparity>] [--scale=scale_factor>] [-i <intrinsic_filename>] [-e <extrinsic_filename>]\n"
           "[--no-display] [-o <disparity_image>] [-p <point_cloud_file>]\n");
}

static void saveXYZ(const char* filename, const Mat& mat)
{
    const double max_z = 1.0e4;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wt");
    for(int y = 0; y < mat.rows; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < mat.cols; x++)
        {
            Vec3f point = mat.at<Vec3f>(y, x);
            if(fabs(point[2] - max_z) < FLT_EPSILON || fabs(point[2]) > max_z) continue;
            fprintf(fp, "%f %f %f\n", point[0], point[1], point[2]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* algorithm_opt = "--algorithm=";
    const char* maxdisp_opt = "--max-disparity=";
    const char* blocksize_opt = "--blocksize=";
    const char* nodisplay_opt = "--no-display=";
    const char* scale_opt = "--scale=";

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        print_help();
        return 0;
    }
    const char* img1_filename = 0;
    const char* img2_filename = 0;
    const char* intrinsic_filename = 0;
    const char* extrinsic_filename = 0;
    const char* disparity_filename = 0;
    const char* point_cloud_filename = 0;

    enum { STEREO_BM=0, STEREO_SGBM=1, STEREO_HH=2, STEREO_VAR=3 };
    int alg = STEREO_SGBM;
    int SADWindowSize = 0, numberOfDisparities = 0;
    bool no_display = false;
    float scale = 1.f;

    StereoBM bm;
    StereoSGBM sgbm;
    StereoVar var;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        if( argv[i][0] != '-' )
        {
            if( !img1_filename )
                img1_filename = argv[i];
            else
                img2_filename = argv[i];
        }
        else if( strncmp(argv[i], algorithm_opt, strlen(algorithm_opt)) == 0 )
        {
            char* _alg = argv[i] + strlen(algorithm_opt);
            alg = strcmp(_alg, "bm") == 0 ? STEREO_BM :
                  strcmp(_alg, "sgbm") == 0 ? STEREO_SGBM :
                  strcmp(_alg, "hh") == 0 ? STEREO_HH :
                  strcmp(_alg, "var") == 0 ? STEREO_VAR : -1;
            if( alg < 0 )
            {
                printf("Command-line parameter error: Unknown stereo algorithm\n\n");
                print_help();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if( strncmp(argv[i], maxdisp_opt, strlen(maxdisp_opt)) == 0 )
        {
            if( sscanf( argv[i] + strlen(maxdisp_opt), "%d", &numberOfDisparities ) != 1 ||
                numberOfDisparities < 1 || numberOfDisparities % 16 != 0 )
            {
                printf("Command-line parameter error: The max disparity (--maxdisparity=<...>) must be a positive integer divisible by 16\n");
                print_help();
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if( strncmp(argv[i], blocksize_opt, strlen(blocksize_opt)) == 0 )
        {
            if( sscanf( argv[i] + strlen(blocksize_opt), "%d", &SADWindowSize ) != 1 ||
                SADWindowSize < 1 || SADWindowSize % 2 != 1 )
            {
                printf("Command-line parameter error: The block size (--blocksize=<...>) must be a positive odd number\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if( strncmp(argv[i], scale_opt, strlen(scale_opt)) == 0 )
        {
            if( sscanf( argv[i] + strlen(scale_opt), "%f", &scale ) != 1 || scale < 0 )
            {
                printf("Command-line parameter error: The scale factor (--scale=<...>) must be a positive floating-point number\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if( strcmp(argv[i], nodisplay_opt) == 0 )
            no_display = true;
        else if( strcmp(argv[i], "-i" ) == 0 )
            intrinsic_filename = argv[++i];
        else if( strcmp(argv[i], "-e" ) == 0 )
            extrinsic_filename = argv[++i];
        else if( strcmp(argv[i], "-o" ) == 0 )
            disparity_filename = argv[++i];
        else if( strcmp(argv[i], "-p" ) == 0 )
            point_cloud_filename = argv[++i];
        else
        {
            printf("Command-line parameter error: unknown option %s\n", argv[i]);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if( !img1_filename || !img2_filename )
    {
        printf("Command-line parameter error: both left and right images must be specified\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( (intrinsic_filename != 0) ^ (extrinsic_filename != 0) )
    {
        printf("Command-line parameter error: either both intrinsic and extrinsic parameters must be specified, or none of them (when the stereo pair is already rectified)\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( extrinsic_filename == 0 && point_cloud_filename )
    {
        printf("Command-line parameter error: extrinsic and intrinsic parameters must be specified to compute the point cloud\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int color_mode = alg == STEREO_BM ? 0 : -1;
    Mat img1 = imread(img1_filename, color_mode);
    Mat img2 = imread(img2_filename, color_mode);

    if( scale != 1.f )
    {
        Mat temp1, temp2;
        int method = scale < 1 ? INTER_AREA : INTER_CUBIC;
        resize(img1, temp1, Size(), scale, scale, method);
        img1 = temp1;
        resize(img2, temp2, Size(), scale, scale, method);
        img2 = temp2;
    }

    Size img_size = img1.size();

    Rect roi1, roi2;
    Mat Q;

    if( intrinsic_filename )
    {
        // reading intrinsic parameters
        FileStorage fs(intrinsic_filename, CV_STORAGE_READ);
        if(!fs.isOpened())
        {
            printf("Failed to open file %s\n", intrinsic_filename);
            return -1;
        }

        Mat M1, D1, M2, D2;
        fs["M1"] >> M1;
        fs["D1"] >> D1;
        fs["M2"] >> M2;
        fs["D2"] >> D2;

        M1 *= scale;
        M2 *= scale;

        fs.open(extrinsic_filename, CV_STORAGE_READ);
        if(!fs.isOpened())
        {
            printf("Failed to open file %s\n", extrinsic_filename);
            return -1;
        }

        Mat R, T, R1, P1, R2, P2;
        fs["R"] >> R;
        fs["T"] >> T;

        stereoRectify( M1, D1, M2, D2, img_size, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, -1, img_size, &roi1, &roi2 );

        Mat map11, map12, map21, map22;
        initUndistortRectifyMap(M1, D1, R1, P1, img_size, CV_16SC2, map11, map12);
        initUndistortRectifyMap(M2, D2, R2, P2, img_size, CV_16SC2, map21, map22);

        Mat img1r, img2r;
        remap(img1, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
        remap(img2, img2r, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);

        img1 = img1r;
        img2 = img2r;
    }

    numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities > 0 ? numberOfDisparities : ((img_size.width/8) + 15) & -16;

    bm.state->roi1 = roi1;
    bm.state->roi2 = roi2;
    bm.state->preFilterCap = 31;
    bm.state->SADWindowSize = SADWindowSize > 0 ? SADWindowSize : 9;
    bm.state->minDisparity = 0;
    bm.state->numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities;
    bm.state->textureThreshold = 10;
    bm.state->uniquenessRatio = 15;
    bm.state->speckleWindowSize = 100;
    bm.state->speckleRange = 32;
    bm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;

    sgbm.preFilterCap = 63;
    sgbm.SADWindowSize = SADWindowSize > 0 ? SADWindowSize : 3;

    int cn = img1.channels();

    sgbm.P1 = 8*cn*sgbm.SADWindowSize*sgbm.SADWindowSize;
    sgbm.P2 = 32*cn*sgbm.SADWindowSize*sgbm.SADWindowSize;
    sgbm.minDisparity = 0;
    sgbm.numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities;
    sgbm.uniquenessRatio = 10;
    sgbm.speckleWindowSize = bm.state->speckleWindowSize;
    sgbm.speckleRange = bm.state->speckleRange;
    sgbm.disp12MaxDiff = 1;
    sgbm.fullDP = alg == STEREO_HH;

    var.levels = 3;                                 // ignored with USE_AUTO_PARAMS
    var.pyrScale = 0.5;                             // ignored with USE_AUTO_PARAMS
    var.nIt = 25;
    var.minDisp = -numberOfDisparities;
    var.maxDisp = 0;
    var.poly_n = 3;
    var.poly_sigma = 0.0;
    var.fi = 15.0f;
    var.lambda = 0.03f;
    var.penalization = var.PENALIZATION_TICHONOV;   // ignored with USE_AUTO_PARAMS
    var.cycle = var.CYCLE_V;                        // ignored with USE_AUTO_PARAMS
    var.flags = var.USE_SMART_ID | var.USE_AUTO_PARAMS | var.USE_INITIAL_DISPARITY | var.USE_MEDIAN_FILTERING ;

    Mat disp, disp8;
    //Mat img1p, img2p, dispp;
    //copyMakeBorder(img1, img1p, 0, 0, numberOfDisparities, 0, IPL_BORDER_REPLICATE);
    //copyMakeBorder(img2, img2p, 0, 0, numberOfDisparities, 0, IPL_BORDER_REPLICATE);

    int64 t = getTickCount();
    if( alg == STEREO_BM )
        bm(img1, img2, disp);
    else if( alg == STEREO_VAR ) {
        var(img1, img2, disp);
    }
    else if( alg == STEREO_SGBM || alg == STEREO_HH )
        sgbm(img1, img2, disp);
    t = getTickCount() - t;
    printf("Time elapsed: %fms\n", t*1000/getTickFrequency());

    //disp = dispp.colRange(numberOfDisparities, img1p.cols);
    if( alg != STEREO_VAR )
        disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8U, 255/(numberOfDisparities*16.));
    else
        disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8U);
    if( !no_display )
    {
        namedWindow("left", 1);
        imshow("left", img1);
        namedWindow("right", 1);
        imshow("right", img2);
        namedWindow("disparity", 0);
        imshow("disparity", disp8);
        printf("press any key to continue...");
        fflush(stdout);
        waitKey();
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(disparity_filename)
        imwrite(disparity_filename, disp8);

    if(point_cloud_filename)
    {
        printf("storing the point cloud...");
        fflush(stdout);
        Mat xyz;
        reprojectImageTo3D(disp, xyz, Q, true);
        saveXYZ(point_cloud_filename, xyz);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I have tried all of the algorithms on the following set of images:
http://imageshack.com/a/img607/4641/utam.jpg (left)
http://imageshack.com/a/img62/5939/2hkc.jpg (right)

Here is my result: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img856/4274/1n50.jpg

And here is the desired result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9PBr.jpg

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

change parameters! For example, say bm, my experience is SADWindowSize  and minDisparity really matters a lot! so you can add trackbars for each parameter and play with it until you get desired result. I've tried the same pair of images and it works fine. So all you need to do it try, try and try parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds crazy, but I had similar output when I was accidentally passing the same image as both the left and right input to the SGBMStereo algorithm.  Just taking a shot in the dark...